# username "white list" check

Tags: c++, file

first of all, I am a beginner in c++
I am doing some training and I want to implement LoginSystem with c++
I am doing a new function for new users and I want them to choose a new username for the account
But I have a file ->Profane_Word_List.txt that has bad words. and I want to check if the user inputted a bad username or fine that I could put it.
my problem is, how I can match the string that the user had inputted and the file usernames.
thank you.

```
#include "LoginSystem.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void LoginSystem::SetUserName(string UserName)
{
    cout << "Hello new User Please choose an username" << endl;

    ifstream ReadFile("Profane_Word_List.txt");
    while (getline(ReadFile, UserName))
    {
        if (UserName==ReadFile)
        {
           //  bad name try again etc.
        }
        
        
            this->_UserName = UserName;
            cout << "user name is updated to:" << _UserName << endl;
        
    }
    
    ReadFile.close();
}
```

Comment: You want to use not white list but black list, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to overwrite the argument by what is read from file.
You should allocate another `string` variable to read from file and compare the argument `UserName` with that.

```
#include "LoginSystem.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void LoginSystem::SetUserName(string UserName)
{
    cout << "Hello new User Please choose an username" << endl;

    ifstream ReadFile("Profane_Word_List.txt");
    string FileLine; // allocate another variable
    while (getline(ReadFile, FileLine)) // read to the new variable
    {
        if (UserName==FileLine) // compare the argument and what is read
        {
           //  bad name try again etc.
        }
        
        
            this->_UserName = UserName;
            cout << "user name is updated to:" << _UserName << endl;
        
    }
    
    ReadFile.close();
}
```

Comment: if (UserName==FileLine) //the problem is with the if statment, IT isnt working
        {
           //  bad name try again etc.
        }